# removeSubrange produces '()', not the expected contextual result type 'String'

Tags: swift

```
static func trimBefore(string: inout String, char: Character) -> String {

    var newString = ""

    if let charRange = string.range(of: String(char)) {
        newString = string.removeSubrange(string.startIndex..<charRange.upperBound)
    }
    return newString
}

static func trimAfter(string: inout String, char: Character) -> String {

    var newString = ""

    if let charRange = string.range(of: String(char)) {
        newString = string.removeSubrange(charRange.lowerBound..<string.endIndex)
    }
    return newString
}
```

I am getting the error in the title. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: `removeSubrange` doesn't return anything, it mutates the string that you call it on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem started when I tried print(extInfo.trimBefore(char: "."). This returned ().

When I changed it to:

```
extInfo.trimAfter(char: ".")
print(extInfo)
```

It worked as expected.

```
mutating func trimBefore(char: Character) {

    if let charRange = self.range(of: String(char)) {
        self.removeSubrange(self.startIndex..<charRange.upperBound)
    }
}

mutating func trimAfter(char: Character) {

    if let charRange = self.range(of: String(char)) {
        self.removeSubrange(charRange.lowerBound..<self.endIndex)
    }
}
```